# How to use infix notation in Android properly (Kotlin language)?

Tags: infix-notation

I have read Kotlin docs as well as the wikipedia links ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation#:~:text=Infix%20notation%20is%20the%20notation,plus%20sign%20in%202%20%2B%202](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation#:%7E:text=Infix%20notation%20is%20the%20notation,plus%20sign%20in%202%20%2B%202)), but unfortunately I am still unable to make use of this notation in my code.

Could someone please let me know, how can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before jumping on to the code, let’s look at the rules of it’s usage (From the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#infix-notation):

1. **Infix** notation must be used with member functions or extension functions
2. They must have a single parameter
3. The parameter must not accept variable number of arguments and must have no default value.

Keeping these pointers in mind, you can achieve the following:

```
fun Int.add(x: Int) = this.plus(x) //This is a simple Extension function without infix notation
```

```
infix fun Int.subtract(x: Int) = this.minus(x) //Added infix notation here
```

```
fun main() {
    val sum = 10.add(20)
    println(sum) //prints 30

    val sub = 100 subtract 30 //Notice that there is no dot(.) and parenthesis
    println(sub) //prints 70
}
```

This is how we can use **infix** notations and get rid of the dots(.) and parenthesis and they will work the same.
This **increases code readability.**

Comment: oh ok. I was going wrong between the rule number 2 and 3. My method was taking 2 arguments and both of them were having default values. That's why I was unable to use this notation.

This makes sense to me now. Thanks for your detailed answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: yeah, even I was confused first when I tried to use infix with a method accepting more than 1 parameter. Then I read the rules from the docs and it got clarified.

Comment: 'infix' modifier is inapplicable on this function: must have a single value parameter why is this?